# Combination & Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have a lot of trouble setting up this problem. Can someone please provide some info to guide me in the right direction?

Question:

Local residents were asked which area teams they support. 122 support at least one team. 16 support only the Barcelona, 16 support Barcelona and Manchester United, and 35 support Barcelona and Chelsea F.C. Of those who support another team in addition to the Barcelona, 2 support both. 1 support only Manchester United, and 45 support Manchester United and Chelsea F.C.. 2 residents do not support any of the teams. Calculate the probability for each given event.

1. A randomly selected resident supports the Barcelona or  Manchester United
2. A randomly selected resident supports exactly one team
3. A randomly selected resident supports the Barcelona but not Chelsea F.C.

[image]

Based on the Venn Diagram above I came up with the answers below:

1. (14,1)/(124,1)
2. (16,1) + (13,1) + (1,1) /(124,1)
3. 1-(16,1) + (13,1)/(124,1)

Can someone please confirm this is correct?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you drawn the Venn diagram?

Comment: Also, when you write "(16,1)," do you mean the binomial coefficient "$16\choose1$"?

Comment: I forgot about Venn diagram completely, but I have now added one. I am not sure if it is correct though.  Yes, I mean binomial coefficient.

Comment: There are various errors in the way you converted the numbers in the problem into entries in the Venn diagram.  The most serious is that you have $18+0=18$ residents who support Barcelona and Manchester instead of $16$, $47+0=47$ who support Manchester and Chelsea instead of $45$, and $37+0=37$ who support Barcelona and Chelsea instead of $35$.  You also have $0$ supporting all three, whereas the problem says there are $2$.  (Also, I think you meant to put a $1$ in the Manchester-only region, and you left the Chelsea-only region blank.)

Comment: I just don't know how to interpret this part of the question into the Venn Diagram: "Of those who support another team in addition to the Barcelona, 2 support both. 1 support only Manchester United, and 45 support Manchester United and Chelsea F.C.. 2 residents do not support any of the teams. Calculate the probability for each given event."

Comment: I edited the Venn diagram. Can you please confirm the changes are correct? Also, where does it mention that two residents support all three teams? I only see this: "2 residents do not support any of the teams."

Comment: The first sentence tells you to put a $2$ in the center region, where all three circles overlap.  The first part of the second sentence says to put a $1$ in the Manchester-only region (where you put a $2$).  The second part says that the numbers in the two regions where the Manchester and Chelsea circles overlap should sum to $45$; since you've already put a $2$ in one of those regions, the other should have a $45-2=43$.

Comment: The "2 residents do not support any of the teams" means that there's a $2$ outside all the circles.  In particular, when you combine this with the very first sentence that "122 support at least one team," that means there is a total of $122+2=124$ residents.  That number will become the denominator in your probability calculations.

Comment: Thanks Barry for all your help. Just updated the Venn Diagram. Can you confirm it is correct?

Comment: Your updated Venn diagram still has various incorrect numbers.  To a certain extent this problem is an exercise in very patiently interpreting the information given and then even more patiently doublechecking that everything is correct.

Comment: I updated it for one last time. Can you confirm for me please? Thanks!!!

Comment: You still have $16=2=18$, not $16$, and $35+2=37$, not $35$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $16+2=18$, not $16=2=18$....

Comment: updated Venn Diagram again. This time I think I nailed it. Yes?

Comment: It looks good to me.  Now you're ready to tackle the questions themselves.  Good going!

Comment: I updated my question with the answers I came up with for questions based on the Venn Diagram

Answer (score 1):

All three probabilities will have the total population, $122+2=124$, in the denominator.  The numerators will come from identifying the appropriate regions of the Venn diagram and summing the numbers in those regions.

For part 1, the numerator is the sum of the numbers in the *union* of the B and M circles, i.e., $16+1+14+43+33+2=109$, so the probability is $109\over124$.  (Note, a quicker way to get the numerator here is to use the fact that the sum of *all* the numbers inside the three circles is $122$, so you can simply subtract the one number not used:  $122-13=109$.)

For part 2, the numerator is the sum of three numbers:  $16+1+13=30$, so the probability is $30\over124$.  (The OP's answer was correct.)

For part 3, the numerator is the sum of the numbers that are *inside* the B circle but *outside* the C circle:  $16+14=30$, so the probability is $30\over124$.

A final note:  Since you're only choosing *one* resident in each part, there is no need to use the binomial coefficient notation, since ${n\choose1}=n$ for all (positive) integers $n$.